# Error: Rake Aborted. Uninitialized Constant Settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, development-environment

Newbie here trying to create a development environment for a project. I've installed MySQL and Ruby on Rails on my device already. However, I'm running into the below error message when trying to run the 3 commands below after "bundle install" runs successfully. Any ideas?

1. `bundle exec rake db:setup RAILS_ENV="development"`
2. `bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV="development"`
3. `bundle exec rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=“development"`

error message is as follows:

```
wcai-projects already exists
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Settings
```

EDIT-here's the console log:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:setup RAILS_ENV=development
/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:270: warning: circular argument reference - now
wcai-projects already exists
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Settings
/wcai-web/config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
/wcai-web/config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/wcai-web/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:setup => db:schema:load_if_ruby => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

EDIT-contents of config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',       # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => Settings.aws_access_key,      # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => Settings.aws_secret_key       # required
#    :region                 => 'eu-west-1'  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = Settings.aws_bucket                    # required
  config.fog_public     = false     
  config.fog_authenticated_url_expiration = 120
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}  # optional, defaults to {}
  #config.asset_host     = 'https://assets.example.com'            # optional, defaults to nil

end
```

Comment: can you please post the console log?

Comment: Sure, please see above edit.

Comment: post contents of `config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb`

Answer (score 1):

Update your Rails version in `Gemfile` to 4.2.4. Then type `bundle update rails` and try again.

Comment: ran into the below error: 

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1) was resolved to 3.2.2, which depends on
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1) was resolved to 3.2.2, which depends on
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    devise was resolved to 3.5.3, which depends on
      railties (< 5, >= 3.2.6)
    jquery-rails was resolved to 3.1.4, which depends on
      railties (< 5.0, >= 3.0)
    rails (= 4.2.4) was resolved to 4.2.4, which depends on
      railties (= 4.2.4)